# Need Reminder Application to notify every X minutes during the day

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

Can one advise an application that can notify me each 1 hr 30 minutes during the day (let's say I can specify it to be from 10 AM till 11 PM).
I've tried Alarmed, Beep me, AidaReminder but all of them can not handle this simple task with almost no effort of the user.

The point is: if I want to arrange my everyday life and get used to:

- Take pills at certain time
- Smoke just 1 time in 2.5 hr
- Have meals at a certain time
- Take work breaks once in every 45 minutes that are lasting for 10 minutes
- Plan to go to a gym every 3 days
- Go to swimming pool every 2 days
- Pay rent every 15th day of every month
- etc.

I know most there is a calendar and simple alarm for most of those tasks, for productivity at work there is pomodoro technique, for tasks like repeating an event (let's say allowing me to smoke once in 2.5 hr) I still have not found a good solution.

I want everything to be in one place. I need an app that I can say:

- Repeat event every 2 hours 25 minutes from 10 AM to 4 PM
- Remind me to pay rent every 15th day at 10 AM
- After every 45 minutes ask me to take an action and go to a 10 minutes break, notify when break is over and ask me to take action to get back to the work or postpone

Is there any good app that meet those exact problems?

***Disclaimer***: I've read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) and I've found this question might be considered as falling into category of `Questions that are primarily opinion-based`, but I want to point this out: I've listed *exact* application responsibilities, so that's it: the application is meet the requirement or not, no place for subjectivity.

Comment: Why exactly is setting up calendar entries not an option for you?

Comment: Calendar app can not take care of repetitive tasks with arbitrary repetition time. Task: I want an even to beep every 15 seconds during the day. How this is done in Calendar app?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Due](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/due-reminders-countdown-timers/id390017969?mt=8). It has a Mac version as well, and I've not seen a more powerful timer app.

Comment: This seems to be the closest to what I want. It also comes with this named timer notion. Like it so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your reminders to Go the the Gym, Pay Rent, Go Swimming, Take Pills and Have Meals can all be done easily using the Calendar while creating a daily or monthly reminder.

You can set an alert to take a break but you need to set the exact time and then when the break should end, e.g. you can set a smoke break for 10am and that break will end at 10:18am; something like that and you can repeat the break every day. However, there isn't a way to repeat the break every 2 hours, etc. You will need to manually enter the start time of the break and then request a daily repeat of the same break using the same time.

Personally, I need a way to set an alert that begins when I start it and lasts for 5 minutes and then repeats every 5 minutes until I stop it manually, but I haven't found anything that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Free app:
Alarmed by "Yoctoville" does it on IOS. Can sync with iCloud too.

However Alarmed broke for me recently on IOS, it keeps crashing no matter what I do (reinstall, restart/app/phone).

The Due App does not have nearly as many features.

EDIT:
the alarmed app worked when I followed instructions here & reset my settings:
http://yoctoville.com/workarounds

I can recommend this app a lot!

Comment: I wouldn't think an app which requires you to reset your settings (and content?) for it to work is recommendable...

Comment: I know it sounds counterintuitive. But the features Alarmed has outweigh this little downside by a lot. Other apps just do not solve the things that I use Alarmed for. I used the app for 3 years and never had any sort of problems. This is the first occurence and it is solvable.


Just check alarmed out for yourself, any other app only has a subset of its features I feel like.

Comment: Well actually, most users wouldn't reset their settings (and content) just to download an app, just sayin'

Comment: You might be right. For most users this is probably the case, it's risky. You need to outweigh the pros & cons. However currently I did not need to reset any content to use/download the app. Some unlucky ones might have to! For me the benefits of this app clearly outweigh the risks as I am using iCloud backup too which is always accessible.

Comment: Yep, so you just reset your settings then? Not content?

Comment: Exactly. Had to reset IOS settings as described in the article. All content still there as it was. The app can backup through iCloud drive if you pay a small one time payment so I still had everything on my Mac/iPad. And then it synced on iPhone.